# Combining Header files for a library

Tags: c++, static, header

I was wondering, when making your own static library, is it a good idea to combine all the header files into one wrapper header file? For example, let say I have a bunch of *.h and *.cpp files, which I compiled into *.lib files. Is  it good practice to make a wrapper header file, so when I write include, I only have to include one header, which will include everything else, which I may or may not need. Does this bloat up the *.exe file, which would have been linked to the library file with the stuff that wasn't being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a static library, it is going to become part of exe anyway whether you make it one header or several headers. However, from a design perspective, it is better to keep headers separate so that the user of that lib includes only the headers that he specifically needs.

Comment: To be precise, the linker pulls only required individual object files from a static library. A possible result is that it pulls 0 object files, i.e. a superfluous static library in the linker command line,

Comment: But it terms of organization, is it better to keep them separate?

Comment: @mma1480: Yes, this will avoid unnecessary linkages as well.